# How to disable GitLab project repository via API?

Tags: java, gitlab, gitlab-api

There is a possibility to disable project repository from GitLab

> Settings->Sharing and permissions->Project Visibility->Repository

and then from menu choose "**Disable**" and "**Save**" at the end.

How can I disable the repository via GitLab API -Java?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was recently proposed in the Product Issue Tracker [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/40892#)